# Convert date & time string to moment.js with timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have user inputs of `meeting_time` which is javascript Date (calendar select) and `meeting_time` string (select dropdown option)

```
var userTime = meeting_time ? meeting_time.label.split(' -')[0] : null
var userDate = moment(meeting_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

How Do I converting those variable to moment.js object with specific timezone

For example,

- `meeting_date` is Thu Jul 12 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
- `meeting_time` is 15:00 - 15:30

I want to get moment `_d` Thu Jul 12 2018 20:00:00 GMT+0800 (UTC +3 to UTC +8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hour and minute in the date.

```
const [hour, minute] = userTime.split(':');
moment(meeting_date).hour(hour).minute(minute).toDate();
```